# Using LINQ in C# to select some elements

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ in C# to access some element of a data strucuture.
Model is my data structure and model.ErrorCollection contains possible errors in the Model.

With the following code I'm able to run my application if there are no errors, except those listed (ErrorType1, ErrorType2, ErrorTypeN) that are tolerated, so if they are found the application runs anyway.

```
if (null != model  && !model.ErrorCollection.Any(e =>
!(e is ErrorType1 || e is ErrorType2 || e is ErrorTypeN)) )
 {
  //do something
 }
```

But what I really need, is the opposite: I want to run my application tolerating any error, except those listed there. If one of them is found, the application must not run.

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

Comment: Just remove negation operator `!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the second negation operator should do it:

```
if (model != null && !model.ErrorCollection.Any(
        e => e is ErrorType1 || e is ErrorType2 || e is ErrorTypeN))
{
    //do something
}
```